# Could not find method implementationSdkVersion() for arguments [26] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension

Tags: android

Screenshot of the code is here i also replaced compile with implementation. I used latest version of android studio.

[image]

Comment: I have taken a screenshot of the answer for you. Unfortunately though, I cannot add screenshots to this comment

Comment: Please do not take screenshots of your code as it can make it difficult to find the problem. Please paste the code directly into the question instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `compileSdkVersion` at the top of the `android` section of your `build.gradle` file, not `implementationSdkVersion`. `implementation` is only used for dependency imports within the `dependencies` section.

Comment: I also did that but after i write compileSdkVersion then there is other issue

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: That must be elsewhere in your `build.gradle` file. There's no way that would be an error for the `compileSdkVersion` line. Can you [edit your queston](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50697349/edit) to include your entire `build.gradle` file **as text**?

Comment: @Osaimjaan I note that you've unaccepted this answer - is there any other issues you'd like me to address?